# Adding/Deleting numbers in an array via user input

Tags: ruby

I want to add/remove numbers in an array based on user input. Here's what I tried:

```
a = %w[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
delete_list = []

puts a
puts "pick 1-9 to del"
input = gets.to_i
input << a
puts a
```

The last line is to check if it worked, and I get `"no implicit conversion of Array into Integer"`. Is this because I used `%w` and the array isn't integer based?

---

```
a = %w[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
a.map! {|e| e.to_i}

puts a
puts "pick 1-9 to del"
input = gets.chomp

a.delete(input)

puts a
```

Well, I changed it up like so. But I don't seem to be having success with the a.delete(input) command, as my array still prints out 1-9. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To remove an element at specific position use [`Array#delete_at`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-delete_at):

```
input = gets.to_i
a.delete_at(input - 1) # index starts from `0`
```

If you want to delete item not by position, but by value, use [`Array#delete`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-delete).

```
input = gets.chomp # `a` contains strings; used `.chomp` instead of `.to_i`
a.delete(input)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is because the argument to `Fixnum#<<` has to be an integer, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

Focusing on the key lines of code:

```
a = %w[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

This makes the variable "a" an array of string elements:

```
 => ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
```

Then you set this variable:

```
input = gets.to_i
```

This gets a string from the user ("gets" - like an abbreviation of the name getStringFromUser) and then `.to_i` turns it to an integer.
This would have likely resulted in a "0" (if letters entered) or whatever integer was entered:
`=>0`    OR    `=> #some integer`

Then you tried to put an array into the integer:

```
input << a
```

Ruby tried to take the "a" array of elements (class Array) and cram it into that integer (aka: class Fixnum) variable "input". This is where you got your error - Ruby can't put an array into an integer using a method like "<<".

If you replaced the line:

```
input << a
```

With:

```
a << input
```

You'll at least get a functional result.
If the "gets" was say, input=9, then your last `puts a` would give you:

```
=> ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", 9]
```

Which is an Array element that consists of a bunch of string elements and an integer element that was pushed to the end.

Now, from your `puts "pick 1-9 to del"`, it seems like you want to delete an element from the array.

First, you'll want your array to be integers and not strings... something like:

```
a.map! {|e|e.to_i}
```

=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

(if you hadn't converted the input to an integer, you could skip that last step... or oddly convert the "input" back to a string with `input.to_s`)

Now that "a" is an array of integers, you can delete one using the "delete" method for Arrays and telling it to delete the value of the "input" variable:

```
a.delete(input)

=> 9
```

#it returns the value you deleted.

Your last `puts a` would return:

```
   => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

It's a long step-wise answer, but hopefully that helps.